# Combine facet_wrap of line plot(1st dataset) with facet_wrap of point plot(2nd dataset) on single plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have two datsets I call them 1.data 2.data_other

1.data

```
data <- read.table(text = "Me EE  PE   DE    TE    DEE   CE
1   1  1 4.5 2000  0.50 0.2547 0.69
2   1  2 2.4 3000    NA 0.5896 2.56
3   1  3 6.5 2345 15.24     NA 1.85
4   1  4  NA   NA 18.23 1.2594 2.06
5   2  1 2.6   NA 12.25 1.5943 2.34
6   2  2  NA 3145 10.25     NA   NA
7   2  3 2.7 4235    NA     NA 2.90
8   2  4  NA   NA  6.32 2.5990 3.18
9   3  1 3.5   NA  8.25 2.9339 3.46
10  3  2 3.8   NA    NA     NA   NA
11  3  3  NA   NA    NA 3.6037 1.58
12  3  4 4.4 4325    NA 3.9386 4.30
13  4  1 4.7   NA 15.24 4.2735 4.58
14  4  2  NA 4325  6.66     NA   NA
15  4  3 5.3   NA 25.20     NA   NA
16  4  4 5.6 3256    NA 5.2782 5.42
17  5  1  NA 4351 25.36 5.6131 5.70
18  5  2 6.2 2345    NA 5.9480   NA
19  5  3 6.5   NA 19.36     NA   NA
20  5  4  NA 4643 17.25 6.6178 6.54", header = T)
```

2.data_other

```
Me  EE  PE  DE  TE  DEE CE
1   1   1.3 1452    12.5    0.2587  1.25
1   2   1.7 2458    10.8    1.5469  0.69
1   3   0.8 3524    11.96   0.5874  0.87
1   4   0.7 1905    13.58   0.9654  0.98
2   1   0.5 2941    12.54   0.2548  1.65
2   2   0.2 3183.5  13.134  1.3658  1.11
2   3   0.01    3426    13.42   0.48692 1.320666667
2   4   1.52    3668.5  13.706  1.9547  1.386095238
3   1   1.98    3911    13.992  0.36906 1.45152381
3   2   2.1 4153.5  14.278  0.31013 1.516952381
3   3   2.44    6674    15.96   0.564   0.2512  
3   4   2.736   6671    16.5    1.85    1.5687  
4   1   1.05    4881    15.136  0.13334 1.713238095
4   2   1.52    5123.5  15.422  0.07441 1.778666667
4   3   0.95    5366    15.708  0.01548 1.844095238
4   4   1.073   5608.5  15.994  1.2548  1.90952381
5   1   1.0233  5851    16.28   1.9658  1.974952381
5   2   0.9733  6093.5  16.566  2.2154  2.040380952
5   3   0.9233  6336    16.852  1.2587  2.105809524
5   4   2.45    6578.5  17.138  1.9657  2.171238095
```

I am plotting point graph with data and I am using following code

```
data <- read.table("data.txt")
datad <- melt(data,id.vars = c("Me","EE"),measure.vars= c("PE","DE","TE","DEE","CE"))
ggplot(subset(datad, !is.na(EE)),aes(x=EE,y=value), as.table = T) + 
    geom_point(aes(color=factor(Me)), size = 3) + 
    facet_wrap(~variable, nrow=3, ncol=2, scales = "free_y")
```

I am plotting line plot with data_other and using following code

```
data_other <- read.table("data_other.txt", header = T)
data_otherd <- melt(data_other, id.vars = c("Me","EE"), measure.vars = c("PE","DE","TE","DEE","CE"))
ggplot(subset(data_otherd, !is.na(EE)), aes(x=EE, y=value), as.table = T) +
    geom_line(aes(color = factor (Me))) +
    facet_wrap(~variable, nrow=3, ncol=2, scales = "free_y")
```

Result.

1. data (point graph)

[image]

2. data_other (line graph)

[image]

I am trying to combine both the data sets on to the same plot (Meaning data_other line plot should be overlapped on to the data point plot or vice versa ).

Both the datasets have same number of columns and columns names are also similar.

Without the facet_wrap I know I can use different geom to specify different dataset and plot the line  plot on the point graph. But with facet wrap I dont know how to combine both the dataset.

How to wrap two datasets with different geom on to a single plot.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just one call to `ggplot()` with first data frame and then add `geom_line()` with `data=data_otherd`. As all variable names are the same, `geom_line()` will use the same information that is provided is `aes()` of `ggplot()` (move also `color=factor(Me)` to `aes()` of `ggplot()` call).

```
ggplot(datad,aes(x=EE,y=value,color=factor(Me)))+
      geom_point()+
      geom_line(data=data_otherd)+
      facet_wrap(~variable, nrow=3, ncol=2, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I thought of this idea but never really tried, thought like how can we link two datasets in single facet_wrap without handling it inside facet_wrap. It looks like functions are power full enough to handle many things (just a matter of exploring stuff). Thanks again...:)